# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons-text

I am writing a character filter function, using `commons-text-1.6.jar`.
The log function is okay, but then this error shows up:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils
    cc.openhome.web.EscapeWrapper.getParameter(EscapeWrapper.java:15)
    cc.openhome.controller.Login.doPost(Login.java:30)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    cc.openhome.web.EscapeFilter.doFilter(EscapeFilter.java:16)
```

Code:

```
package cc.openhome.web;

import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrappe

public class EscapeWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public EscapeWrapper(HttpServletRequest req){enter code here
        super(req);
    }

    public String getParameter(String name){
        String value = getRequest().getParameter(name);
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I encountered a similar issue with `commons-text-1.11.0.java`. Despite having `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` present in `commons-text-1.11.0.jar`, I received the following exception:

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils
```

The problem doesn't stem from the absence of `StringEscapeUtils` but rather from its initialization. In fact, `StringEscapeUtils` has multiple static initialization blocks that run when the ClassLoader loads it for the first time. If these static blocks encounter issues during the initial loading, it results in the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

#### Fix

`commons-text` relies on other libraries, notably `commons-lang3`. Inconsistencies in their versions can lead to the exception, as it was in my case:

`commons-text-1.11.0` with `commons-lang3:3.12.0` -> FAIL

However, upgrading `commons-lang3` to `3.13.0` resolved the issue:

`commons-text-1.11.0` with `commons-lang3:3.13.0` -> SUCCESSFUL

While your situation may involve different versions or dependencies, the underlying cause might be the same.